# Distribtution of the maximum of three uniform random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I get the cumulative density function of $Y$? $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf
$$f(x) = 1,\quad   0 < x < 1. $$

Three independent observations of $X$ are made. Find the pdf of $Y$ where $$Y = \max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}.$$

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What have tried yet ?

Comment: Are you looking finally for the pdf or the cdf of $Y$ ?

Comment: Oh yes i know F(x) = x  for      0 < x < 1 which is the CDF of f. I need hint on tying Y to F(x).

Comment: There's no such thing as a "cumulative density function".  The word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density".  There's such a thing as a cumulative probability distribution function and there's such a thing as a probability density function, and they're two different things, and the very meaning of the word "density" implies it's not cumulative. $\qquad$

Comment: Just to add to Michael's comment, [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) stands for cumulative _distribution_ function, not density.

Answer (score 3):

Start by writing the cdf of $Y$ and make the appropriate substitution
$$P(Y\leq y) = P(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\} \leq y).$$ 
Notice that
$$\{\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}\leq y\}\iff\{X_1\leq y,X_2\leq y,X_3\leq y\}$$
Then
\begin{align*}
P(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\} \leq y)&= P(X_1\leq y,X_2\leq y,X_3\leq y)\\
&= P(X_1\leq y)P(X_2\leq y)P(X_3\leq y)\tag 1\\
&=y^3
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I used the the fact that the $X_i$ are independent.
This gives that the pdf of $Y$ is
$$f_Y(y) = 3y^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The pdf or cdf you are looking for is part of what is called the "order statistics": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

The easiest path is through the cdf, using the following transformations:

$F_Y(y) \ = \ P(Y\leq y) \ = P(\max{\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}} \leq y)$

$F_Y(y) \ = \ P(X_1 \leq y \ \& \ X_1 \leq y \ \& \ X_1 \leq y).$

Using independence of the $X_k$:

$F_Y(y) \ = \ P(X_1 \leq y) P(X_2 \leq y) P(X_3 \leq y)=(y)^3$

It suffices then to derive wrt $y$ to obtain the pdf:

$$f_Y(y)=3~y^2$$

Edit : Very sorry : I made a mistake that I have corrected now (confusion between $\min$ and $\max$)

Comment: The **maximum** is *at most* $y$ iff *all* of the values are *at most* $y$.  $$\{\max\{X_i\}\leq y\} ~\equiv~ \bigcap_i \{X_i\leq y\}$$

Comment: Ypu are right. I just noticed it.